# Group homomorphism and equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For each natural number $n$ we are given a group $G_n$ and a group homomorphism $\phi:G_n \rightarrow G_{n+1}$. Define a binary relation on the disjoint union $\amalg_{n=1}^{\infty} G_n$ of these groups. Given $x_n \in G_n $ , $x_m \in G_m$ , we define

$x_n \sim x_m \iff \exists k \geqslant max(m,n)$ such that $\phi_{k-1}...\phi_m(x_m)=\phi_{k-1}...\phi_n(x_n).$

1. How can I prove this is an **equivalence relation**?
2. **Furthermore**, prove that the quotient set $G_\infty=\amalg_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n/\sim$ is a group under the operation $[x_n] \cdot[y_n]=[{x_ny_n}]$ defined on elements $x_n,y_n \in G_n$ for all $n$.

I am having trouble setting the scene with the proof. If I am not wrong, the group $G_\infty$ is the inverse limit of the groups $G_n$.

Comment: The first part is really just applying the definition. For the second part, you need to check that the operation is well-defined, i.e. if  $x \sim \tilde{x}$, $y \sim \tilde{y}$, then $xy \sim \tilde{x}\tilde{y}$.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, this is actually a direct limit or colimit, which is not the same as an inverse limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment provided the answer.